# How should a certain percentage of evenly-distributed elements of a Python list be extracted?

Tags: python, list, distribution, percentage

I have a list of data points. For the full run of my program, I'll use all of the data points, but for testing of the code, I want to use only a small percentage of them in order that the program run in a short time. I do not want simply to take the first n elements of the list, though; I want to select an even distribution of the elements from the list. So, if I'm using 50% of the data points, I might want to select from the list of data points every second data points.

Basically, I want to have a function that takes as arguments a list and a percentage and returns a list consisting of an even distribution of elements from the input list, the number of which corresponds as closely as possible to the percentage requested.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Please read my comments on the answer you set as correct.

Comment: @jojo do note that *accepted* is (deliberately!) not necessarily the same as *"set as correct"* (although users certainly shouldn't accept outright wrong answers) - acceptance just tells you that the OP found that answer most useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added a binning algorithm which minimizes the deviation while choosing equally distributed elements. Your method is much simpler and works well for small fractions (see comparison).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can trivially be achieved by setting a slice with a step:

```
def select_elements(seq, perc):
    """Select a defined percentage of the elements of seq."""
    return seq[::int(100.0/perc)]
```

In use:

```
>>> select_elements(range(10), 50)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> select_elements(range(10), 33)
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>> select_elements(range(10), 25)
[0, 4, 8]
```

You could also add `round`, as `int` will truncate:

```
>>> int(3.6)
3
>>> int(round(3.6))
4
```

If you want to use a proportion rather than a percentage (e.g. `0.5` instead of `50`), simply replace `100.0` with `1`.

Comment: It doesn't look like even distribution in the meaning of the Uniform Distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete). The elements should be selected randomly, shouldn't them?

Comment: @LiMar I don't think the OP means uniform distribution in that sense, I have based this on *"So, if I'm using 50% of the data points, I might want to select from the list of data points every second data points."*.

Comment: [jonsharpe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) Thank you very much for your clear, detailed answer on using a step size in a list slice operation.

[LiMar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/467858/limar) Yes, I used a term that specifically was not "uniform distribution". Thanks for considering that, though. Sampling in a more detailed way like that would likely involve Monte Carlo considerations.

Comment: Please consider `len(select_elements(range(1000), 50))` and `len(select_elements(range(1000), 40))`. Or said differently, with your method choosing 50% is the same as choosing 40%. **In fact everything between 34% and 50% is treated equally...**

Comment: @jojo that's true, due to the way this type of sampling works (i.e. the requirement for even distribution *along the length of the sequence*). Note that using `round`, as I comment in the answer (i.e. `return seq[::int(round(100.0/perc))]`), can improve things slightly (in your example, the switch between `334` and `500` elements in the output moves from `33`-`34` to `40`-`41`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know. Maybe it would be wise to adapt your answer as the method you suggest is far more inaccurate than inevitable. A better approach would be to get the number of elements to pick (`to_pick = len(my_list) *  0.01 * percentage`) then randomly choose this many elements from the list (e.g. `random.shuffle(my_list)` then `my_list[:to_pick]`).

Comment: @jojo Please re-read the question; this method, although not "evenly-distributed" in the mathematical sense, meets the OP's requirements. In general you're right, and `random.sample` would be the appropriate way to do this (although they may give equivalent results in a small subset of cases). I don't know what you mean by *"far more inaccurate than inevitable"*.

Comment: _far more inaccurate than inevitable_: If you have a list of length 10 and you want 42% of it. Then the closest is 4 elements. this is not 42% of 10 though. This inaccuracy of 2% is inevitable. In your case you would get 5 elements which is 50% and thus be 8% off. Please re-read the OP's question: `the number of which corresponds as closely as possible to the percentage requested.` Your method clearly does not do this.

Comment: It gets worse with bigger lists: if you consider a list of 1000 elements, 42% can be matched perfectly: 420 elements. Your method would take 500. We do not need to argue any further on this, please correct your answer.

Comment: @jojo *"I might want to select from the list of data points every second data points"*, which is what this code does. *"We do not need to argue any further on this"* - and indeed I won't bother to do so; I assume that's your downvote, which you're entitled to, but note that the OP has accepted the answer as meeting their requirements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: sure he has, and if he's happy with it then that's fine for me. I just hope you see the issue I'd like to bring to your attention.

Comment: @jojo yes, I completely understand your issue; however, note that this was *already raised by LiMar*, and that the OP commented that my answer *was* what they intended. If you have different requirements, then certainly `random.sample(seq, int(round(len(seq) * perc / 100.0)))` would be a more mathematically correct approach, but it doesn't meet the OP's requirement for even distribution along the length of the list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you mention in your answer the range for which your method performs well/ not so well (e.g. copy the plot with the deviations), I'd be happy to change my down into an up vote.

Comment: @jojo so after all of that you're going to hold me hostage over seven points? Lacks a certain class, don't you think? I appreciate your input, but I see no reason for material to be replicated across multiple answers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wonder what class you are talking about. Your answer is simple and valid in a limited range of possibilities and it is not very accurate outside this range. It would be for the better of the problem to specify where your answer is a good solution and where it performs poorly. But never mind.

Comment: @jojo sorry, I realise that might be ambiguous to those whose first language isn't English. See meaning 3c: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/class

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, consider the following.

The problem can be split up in two part:

1. Determine the number of elements to pick, given a certain percentage or fraction.
2. Choose which elements from the list should be picked.

The first point is straight forward. If you would like to have `percentage = 35. #%` of your list, you'd ideally choose `round(len(my_list) * (percentage / 100.))` elements. Note that you'd get the percentage exactly right only if `len(my_list)` is a multiple of `(percentage / 100.)`. This inaccuracy is inevitable, as a continuous measure (percentage) is converted into a discrete one (nbr. of elements).

The second point will depend upon the special requirements you have towards which element should be returned. Choosing elements as equally distributed as possible is doable but certainly not the easiest way.

Here is how you would do this conceptually (see below for an implementation):

If you have a list of length `l` whereof you'd like a certain equally distributed fraction `f` (`f = percentage / 100.`) you will have to bin the indexes of you list into `round(l * f)` bins of the size `l / round(l * f)`. What you want is the list with the most central elements for each bin.

Why does this work?

For the  first point, note that if we make bins of the size  `l / round(l * f)` we will get `l / l / round(l * f) = round(l * f)` bins at the end. Which is the ideal  amount (see point 1 above). If for each of these equally sized bins we then choose the most central element, we get a list of elements that are as equally distributed as possible.

Here is a simple (and neither speed optimized nor very pretty) implementation of this:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def equal_dist_els(my_list, fraction):
    """
    Chose a fraction of equally distributed elements.
    :param my_list: The list to draw from
    :param fraction: The ideal fraction of elements
    :return: Elements of the list with the best match
    """
    length = len(my_list)
    list_indexes = range(length)
    nbr_bins = int(round(length * fraction))
    step = length / float(nbr_bins)  # the size of a single bin
    bins = [step * i for i in xrange(nbr_bins)]  # list of bin ends
    # distribute indexes into the bins
    splits = [bisect_left(list_indexes, wall) for wall in bins]
    splits.append(length)  # add the end for the last bin
    # get a list of (start, stop) indexes for each bin
    bin_limits = [(splits[i], splits[i + 1]) for i in xrange(len(splits) - 1)]
    out = []
    for bin_lim in bin_limits:
        f, t = bin_lim
        in_bin = my_list[f:t]  # choose the elements in my_list belonging in this bin
        out.append(in_bin[int(0.5 * len(in_bin))])  # choose the most central element
    return out
```

We can now compare this ideal algorithm (equal_dist_els) with the slicing approach by @jonrsharpe:

[image: absolute difference as fct of the requested fraction]

*See further below for the code.*

Along the x-axis is the wished fraction of elements to be returned and on the y-axis is the absolute difference between the wanted fraction and the fraction returned by the two methods. We see that for fractions around 0.7 (~70%) the deviation of the slicing method is remarkable, i.e. if you ask for ~70% the slicing method returns all the elements (100%) which is a deviation of almost 45%.

To conclude we can say that the slicing method by @jonrsharpe works well for small fractions (`>>0.1`) but becomes increasingly inaccurate when choosing bigger fractions. Also note that the inaccuracy is independent of the length of the list. The binning algorithm is certainly slightly more complicated to implement and most probably also much slower. However its inaccuracy is just given by the inevitable inaccuracy mentioned above which decreases with increasing length of the list.

*code for the plots:*

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# def of equal_dist_els see above
def select_els(seq, perc):
    """Select a defined percentage of the elements of seq."""
    return seq[::int(round(1./perc if perc != 0 else 0))]
list_length = 50
my_list = range(list_length)
percentages = range(1, 101)
fracts = map(lambda x: x * 0.01, percentages)

equal_dist = map(lambda x: abs(len(equal_dist_els(my_list, x)) / float(len(my_list)) - x), fracts)
slicing = map(lambda x: abs(len(select_els(my_list, x)) / float(len(my_list)) - x), fracts)

plt.plot(fracts, equal_dist, color='blue', alpha=0.8, linewidth=2, label=r'equal_dist_elements')
plt.plot(fracts, slicing, color='red', alpha=0.8, linewidth=2, label=r'select_elements by @jonrsharpe')
plt.title('Choosing equally dist. fraction of els from a list of length %s' % str(list_length))
plt.xlabel('requested fraction')
plt.ylabel('absolute deviation')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Very neat, but I think comparing the `round`ed version would be fairer; if closeness to `perc`% of the elements was more important than "physical" distribution, you'd start there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Indeed you're right, will change it to the rounded version.

Comment: @jonrsharpe For the version with `round` the maximal deviation drops from 100% to around 45%.