# How could a specified number of elements be extracted from a list with an even distribution?

Tags: python, list, slice

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408226/1556092) shows how one could extract a certain percentage of elements from a list with an even distribution. How could a specified number of elements be extracted from a list with an even distribution?

Comment: do you have a sample with desired output?

Comment: So if you had `elements(range(10), 1)` for one element out of a list 0-9, what do you expect to see? How about `elements(range(10), 2)`?

Comment: Presumably you could use the same method as above, but convert your `specified_number` to a percentage by using `specified_number/len(list)`

Comment: @lambo477, that wouldn't work.  The solution given in the OP's link doesn't really work accurately because of rounding issues.  I don't think slicing can give an exact number, so you'd need to adjust the gap as you go on either side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with a recursive function.  This makes it quicker for me to write, but is not very pythonic, I guess.  Anyway, it gets the job done:

```
>>> def select_elements(myList,num):
    if len(myList)<=num: return myList #Might not be enough elements
    if num==0: return []
    if num==1: return [myList[int(round((len(myList)-1)/2))]]
    return [myList[int(round((len(myList)-1)/(2*num)))]]+select_elements(myList[int(round((len(myList)-1)/(num))):],num-1)

>>> i = range(10)
>>> for j in range(11):
    print(j,select_elements(i,j))


0 []
1 [4]
2 [2, 6]
3 [2, 5, 8]
4 [1, 3, 5, 8]
5 [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
6 [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
8 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
9 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
10 range(0, 10)
```

We could spend all day arguing about what the right distribution would be in some of these scenarios.  It really depends what you want.  The above could be improved somewhat, but I thought I'd get things going...

Comment: It's a little complex, but is a decent solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help